# How to assign a UTC timestamp to extracted csv timestamp which is already in UTC format in Pandas or Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Basically, my data in the excel file is already in the following format: 2003-05-01 00:00:00+09:30 which includes UTC. But when I extract the datetime column to python through pandas, and create a Datetime index for it, I get the dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(570)]. I need it to be dtype: datetime64[ns, utc]
How do I go about this? I am new to python.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cd0f.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xjM0.png)

[image: When I used df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], utc = True), my timestamps got changed]

Comment: Your input is not UTC, it has a UTC offset specified.  +09:30 means 9:30 hours ahead of UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating that `DatetimeIndex`, I believe what you want here is [**`to_datetime()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `utc=True`:

```py
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], utc=True)
```

Comment: Hi, I initially tried that way, but it automatically adjusted my timestamps which I did not want.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], utc = True))
```

After this step the timestamps were changed from the original ones as shown in the pictures I have attached, But I went on to use tz_convert function for the location and the timestamps corrected themselves

```
tz = 'Australia/Darwin'
d = d.tz_convert(tz)
df['Datetime'] = d
```